# Jar mismatch error when adding library in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, shared-libraries, android-viewpager

I am new to Android and I am trying to add a library for viewPagerIndicator as [this tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537) instructs me to do. However, when I add the library I get an error stating:

```
Versions found are:
Path: C:\Users\Bryan\workspace\MyPager\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 349252
SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
Path: C:\Users\Bryan\git\Android-ViewPagerIndicator\library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 271754
SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

How do I resolve this without messing up my build path?

Comment: Are you using Maven or Eclipse build system?

Comment: @arunkumar  I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like it found the library twice.  You need to delete one.

Comment: What is the correct procedure for doing that?  I only see one library in my dependencies folder

Comment: If you've already added some external libraries (like ActionBarSherlock) they sometimes include the support library so you don't even need to add it.  Also, if you set up your SDK targets correctly in your manifest (target the newest SDK and set minSDK) then use the built in activity creater (new file->other->android activity) then it will add the support library for you.

Comment: Just delete the one added to the libs folder of your app

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different revisions of the support library. **Delete all of the support library jars** and **re-copy** them into your app (and any other dependencies, if have).

The **android-support-v4.jar will be compiled** again automatically.

Edit :
Should **remove Android Dependencies and Android Private Libraries** in **Libraries** index in **Java Build Path**

Comment: I deleted my Dependencies folder... How do i get those folders back :(.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove unnecessary .jar file of libs folder from your Android project.