# Jar mismatch error in android when adding library for viewPagerIndicator in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jar

Posible Duplicate of [Jar mismatch error when adding library in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540071/jar-mismatch-error-when-adding-library-in-eclipse)

But i have not getting any help so i am asking it again.

When i create new project in **Eclipse** two folder created

1. Demoapp (project name)
2. appcompact_v7

**Problem:** when i right click project and selecting “Properties|Android”, then clicking “Add…” in the Library section and selecting the ViewPagerIndicator library.

Its giving me error:

```
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Versions found are:
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Path: C:\Users\WebInfoMart\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     Length: 627582
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     SHA-1: cb6883d96005bc85b3e868f204507ea5b4fa9bbf
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Path: C:\Users\WebInfoMart\workspace\DemoApp\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     Length: 627582
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     SHA-1: cb6883d96005bc85b3e868f204507ea5b4fa9bbf
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Path: C:\Users\WebInfoMart\workspace\library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     Length: 271754
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp]     SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
[2014-04-07 17:55:54 - DemoApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

**Already Tried:**
I deleted Demoapp>lib>android-support-v4.jar & appcompact_v7>lib>android-support-v4.jar both files and copied ViewPagerIndicator library>lib>android-support-v4.jar to my **DemoApp** and **appcompact_v7** folder, then clean and rebuild project.

But nothing seems to work. while Sample project of ViewPagerIndicator library is working fine.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue this is how i fixed it as @Raghunandan already answered here [jar mismatch from log cat on program run using google play service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707722/jar-mismatch-from-log-cat-on-program-run-using-google-play-service)

Its because of library and project have different jar file

**Solution :**

Just copy the `android-support-v4.jar` from `sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar` to the libs folder of both **ViewPagerIndicator library project** and **Your Android project**.

Hope this helps

For Tutorial of ViewPagerIndicator http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

Answer (score 0):

Since your ViewPagerIndicator library already have the android-support-v4.jar and so remove it from Demoapp and appcompact_v7, then it will work. As both the projects are inheriting it from the ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: where i found updated version? it was a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Support library from ViewPagerIndicator is an old one, try to update it with the one used in your DemoApp. Then delete it from DemoApp.

There's a pull request open to update the v4 support library for ViewPagerIndicator: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/pull/271